# Perl performance: for(1..200000) vs for($_=1;$_<=200000;$_++)

Tags: perl, performance, memory

`for(1..200000) {...}` vs `for($_=1;$_<=200000;$_++) {...}`

Does the first one have to create an array of 200,000 items or is it just about the same as the second?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: What part of the documentation that explains *this very thing* did you not understand?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can definitively say that `for` with a range (`$lower .. $upper`) doesn't create an actual temporary list in memory. [It did 12 years ago, but not anymore.](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perl5005delta#foreach_(1..1000000)_optimized) And as a matter of fact, it gives *better* performance than the explicit C-style for-loop (as others' benchmarks have shown), because Perl is able to do the counting loop in nice, efficient internal code. You shouldn't be afraid to use it.

Comment: I didn't even see that he asked that :)  I was focused on the question *keyword*: performance

Comment: That explains the 85% better performance of the p_for vs. the c_for (in my own benchmarks, using strawberry 5.12.1).

Comment: @vol7ron as far as I'm concerned, it's the much more important question. One should almost never worry about a couple nanoseconds of overhead per iteration, but one *should* worry about unnecessary O(n) memory usage when it could be O(1). But fortunately this time the matter is simple -- `for (1..n)` wins in all categories.

Comment: I worry about both :) and yes, ur right, it was an important question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ time perl -e '$a=0;for(1..10000000){$a++;}'

real 0m0.523s
user 0m0.520s
sys  0m0.000s

$ time perl -e '$a=0;for($_=1;$_<=10000000;$_++){$a++;}'

real    0m1.309s
user    0m1.300s
sys  0m0.000s
```

So the former is faster, which suggests the answer to your question is a no. It is very likely optimised as `for i in xrange(n)` is in Python.

Comment: Comparable results with 5.12.1 and 5.13.4 on two different pieces of hardware.

Comment: @vol7ron That's probably because the latter method can keep everything in registers for the entire loop when removing access to $a.

Comment: I moved it to my answer, you might want to leave the same comment there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious if it's because you're incrementing both `$_` and `$a` in the second, whereas the first performs an internal increment.

- `time perl -e 'for($_=1;$_<=10000000;){$_++;}'`

  ```
  real    0m0.544s
  user    0m0.540s
  sys     0m0.000s
  ```
- `time perl -e 'for($_=1;$_<=10000000;$_++){$a;}'`

  ```
  real    0m0.593s
  user    0m0.580s
  sys     0m0.000s
  ```

  *both get rid of the additional variable and also have closer results, but they are not equivalent to the original example*

Like JavaScript, a reverse while loop would be even faster than your second method, and slightly slower than your first:

- `time perl -e '$a=0;for($_=10000000;$_--;){$a++;}'`

  ```
  real    0m0.543s
  user    0m0.530s
  sys     0m0.000s
  ```
- `time perl -e '$a=0;$_=10000000;while($_--){$a++;}'`

  ```
  real    0m0.569s
  user    0m0.550s
  sys     0m0.010s
  ```

  *both are equivalent to the original example; however it may not be usable if you can't step backward.  they are closer to your first one's results*