# Is there a way to easily take 3 text files and turn it into a multi-tab excel sheet via script?

Tags: perl, excel, vbscript

Is there a way to easily take 3 text files and turn it into a multi-tab excel sheet via script?

files are file1.txt, file 2.txt, file3.txt - i would like it to output to excelsheet1.xls with 3 tabs.

Comment: Does it actually need to be an .xls? It would be very easy to stick them together in a single .csv file with a Perl script, and on most systems .csv files automatically open in Excel.

Comment: well, i need it in tabs. But, if that is not possible -single csv would be my next option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention the format of the text files so real example code is difficult, but you can use [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) for this. Look at the add_worksheet() method for creating new tabs.

Given that you say that each line is a number followed by text I am presuming that this is two columns per row with a space delimiting the first and second columns and only digits in the first column. If this is not true the regex below would need to be adjusted. That said, here's some sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

sub read_file{
        my $f = shift;
        my @row;
        open(my $fh, '<', $f) or die $!;
        while(<$fh>){
                chomp;
                s/^(d+)s+//; # assuming format of "1 Text heren2 More textn"
                if(defined $1){
                        push(@row, [$1, $_]);
                }
        }
        close($fh) or die $!;

        return @row;
}

if($#ARGV < 1){
        die "$0: file1 [file2 ... filen] output.xls\n";
}
my $xl = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new(pop);

foreach my $file (@ARGV){
        if( -f $file){
                my @rows = read_file($file);
                my $sheet = $xl->add_worksheet($file);
                for my $row (0..$#rows){
                        my @cols = @{$rows[$row]};
                        for my $col (0..$#cols){
                                $sheet->write($row, $col, $cols[$col]);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Input files are given on the command line and processed in order, turning each one in to a tab named after the file name. The output file name is given on the command line last, after one or more input file names.

EDIT: Now including the improvements [FM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55857/fm) mentioned in his comment and a trivial CLI for specifying the output file name.

Comment: The text files are just straight text they all start with a number with a sentence next to the number

Comment: Does this mean "A single column of newline-delimited records"?

Comment: @Sorpigal Useful answer. Would be even better if it used idiomatic `for` loops: `for my $row (0 .. $#rows)`. And if it used lexical file handles: `open(my $fh, '<', $file_name)`. Nitpicking, I suppose. As a side note, also see this recent answer on the two loop styles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330287/perl-performance-for1-200000-vs-for-1-200000/4330560#4330560.

Comment: Hi guys - at first i thought it wasnt showing the data in the tabs because of the text file not being in the correct format but i created the text files as 1234 some text and next line 2342 some text and tried - it created the tabs but no text in the tabs. I also tried it with just 1 hello world in one text file and same thing happened. I could be doing something wrong, any ideas? I am not sure what stackoverflow ettiquette is for this kinda thing.

Comment: I'm not sure, either. Could you provide a link to your input data?